# How to Launch Computer Programs (xlsx file)

Tags: python, pandas, keras, jupyter-notebook

I want to open the `.xlsx` file which I appended in list. I wrote a code to display all subdirectory files with `.xlsx` extension and all the files where appended in list. Can anyone tell me how to display a specific `.xlsx` file in the list which I appended?

```py
import io
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
from pathlib import Path

entries = Path('Daybook Sample for Automation/')
for entry in entries.iterdir():
    for sub_entry in entry.iterdir():
        total=sub_entry.name
        list_append=[]
        list_append.append(total)
        print({total})
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not understand what exactly you mean by open , but you can check this solution to open it with pandas or openpyxl

```
import io
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
from pathlib import Path

list_append = []
entries = Path(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\prodima/')
for entry in entries.iterdir():
    for sub_entry in entry.iterdir():
        if sub_entry.name.endswith('xlsx'):
            total = sub_entry.name
            list_append.append([total, sub_entry])
print(list_append)

for item in list_append:
     if item[0].startswith('AUDI'):
         df = pd.read_excel(item[1])
         # do some thing with  df
         df.to_excel(item[1], index=False)
         print(df)
```

or open it with openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
for item in list_append:
    if item[0].startswith('AUDI'):
        wb = load_workbook(filename=item[1])
        sheet_name = wb.get_sheet_names()
        print(sheet_name)
        sheet_ranges = wb[sheet_name[0]]
        print(sheet_ranges['D18'].value)
```

and finaly Launch your file using subprocess

```
import subprocess

for item in list_append:
    if item[0].startswith('AUDI'):
        subprocess.run([r'C:\Program Files\Microsoft 
                         Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE', item[1]])
```

Comment: Actually i wanted to open the excel file which i appended in the list

Comment: in this way can you  open this file  or not?

Comment: I am trying , actually so if i input a name of the excel file which i appended right now and open them then how can we do it ?

Comment: How to Launch xlsx file  Using Python script ? is that what you look for

Comment: please check the last part in my answer , this work with me